# Ruby returns uninitialized constant error when trying to include a module within a chef recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I have a `java/recipes/windows` recipe that uses a method called `win_friendly_path` and it doesn't work because `win_friendly_path` is not yet defined.

`win_friendly_path` is however defined in the `../windows/libraries/windows_helper.rb` as follows:

```
module Windows
  module Helper
def win_friendly_path(path)
      path.gsub(::File::SEPARATOR, ::File::ALT_SEPARATOR || '\\') if path
    end
```

I already have my `berksfile` and `metadata.rb` setup in the `java (./)` recipe to depend on the `windows` cookbook.

I'm not sure how to include this module so right now I am trying to just use `include WindowsHelper` in the `java/cookbook/windows` recipe and receiving this error:

`uninitialized constant #<Class:#<Chef::Recipe:0x00000000029a2188>>::WindowsHelper`

I have tried several variations of this and now feel like I have spent way too much time troubleshooting the issue so any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: plugging in this line `::Chef::Resource.send(:include, Windows::Helper)` to my `java/recipes/windows` recipe gives me the following error:

```
Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed
       ----------------------------------
       value is a required property
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Inserting the following line resolved this issue for me:

`::Chef::Recipe.send(:include, Windows::Helper)`

This allows me to use the variables following module from the windows cookbook:

```
module Windows
  module Helper
...
{Variable}
  {Other_variable}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
include Windows::Helper
```

Comment: I receive the following error when adding that line: undefined method `include' for cookbook: java, recipe: windows :Chef::Recipe

Comment: Interesting. How about this one: ```Chef::Resource.send(:include, Windows::Helper)``` ?

Comment: I edited my question to include the following: I have tried both Chef::Resource.send(:include, Windows::Helper) and ::Chef::Resource.send(:include, Windows::Helper) resulting in the following error:  value is a required property